# Prevent/Disable BottomSheetScaffold from being swiped/dragged

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet, android-bottomsheetdialog

I have a `BottomSheetScaffold()`, on button push the bottomsheet is coming up, all is working fine, but i want to prevent the user from swiping down the bottomsheet. Instead a button on the bottomsheet is use to close it on click.

I see the option `drawerGesturesEnabled`, but this not doing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set its `sheetGesturesEnabled` parameter to `false`

```
BottomSheetScaffold(
    sheetGesturesEnabled = false,
    …
    …
```

Answer (score 1):

The code above works as long as there is no scrollable content inside.

I had a task to prevent the BottomSheet collapsing by swiping down (or rather, in the process of scrolling nested content). Here is the solution I found (use confirmStateChange callback). I hope this will be useful to someone.

```
val scaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState(
    bottomSheetState = rememberBottomSheetState(
        initialValue = BottomSheetValue.Collapsed,
        confirmStateChange = {
            // Prevent collapsing by swipe down gesture
            it != BottomSheetValue.Collapsed
        }
    ),
    snackbarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }
)
```

Comment: Your solution seems incomplete, please elaborate.